# How to encode my laravel or codeigniter project to protect my code

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, encoding

I finished a laravel application and i want to give it to someone to work with but i don't want him to access to my code, he must just use the application without being able to show how it works !!
There is a way how to encode my code or something like that ?? and if it is, it will not affect the running of the app ??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MyPHPGuard: http://www.mediafire.com/file/2pnh2pjk87c9rhd/myphpguard+installer%2Bportable+1.3.54d.zip

How it works: https://jornadadodev.com.br/posts/php/como-ofuscar-ou-criptografar-o-seu-codigo-php